# AJAX return always false, how to set PHP false

Tags: php, ajax, return

I am beginner in study AJAX.

here is PHP for post action of my form, but somehow it always return false.

```
<?php
session_start();
include"../connection/sambung.php";

$us=$_SESSION['username'];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { //halaman ini harus dipanggil melalui post
$id = $_POST["id"];
$code = $_POST["code"];
$act = $_POST["act"];

switch($act){
//tambah data
case "insert":$sql="INSERT INTO karyawan(nip,nama)VALUES('".$nip."','".$nama."')";$i='1';break;
//edit data
case "validate":$sql="UPDATE member SET validasi=1 WHERE id_member ='".$id."' and kode_member='".$code."'";$i='2';break;
//hapus data
case "delete":$sql="DELETE FROM karyawan WHERE nip = '".$nip."'";$i='2';break;
}
//eksekusi sql
$kueri = mysql_query($sql);

//tampilkan hasil
if($i=='1'){
    if(mysql_num_rows($kueri)){echo "success";}
}
else if($i=='2'){
    if (mysql_affected_rows($kueri)){echo "success";}
    }
else{
    echo "failed";
    }
}else{
echo "This link can't run directly.";
}
?>
```

and the AJAX configuration as follow:

```
$( "#dialog-validate" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
    "Validate": function() {
    var
    aid = $("#idedit").html();
    acode = $("input#codeedit").val();
    aact= 'validate';
    $("#waiting").show();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "applicant/check.php",
    data: {"id":aid,"code":acode,"act":aact},
    timeout: 3000,
    beforeSend: function(){},
    complete: function(){},
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
    if (result=='success'){
    //ubah isi data table sesuai dengan perubahan yang terjadi
    objRow.find(".valcell").html("Yes");
    $("#waiting").hide();

    }else{alert('gagal simpan data');$("#waiting").hide();}
    },
    error: function(error){$("#waiting").hide();alert(error);}
    }
    );

    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

    },
    Cancel: function() {
    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
    }
    }
    });
```

what I need is how to make

```
success: function(result){
    if (result=='success'){
```

result false, I have been changing it many times, PHP or AJAX error? please help

Comment: Check browser console for AJAX errors and apache for php errors?

Comment: the weird one is, when I put the php as plain php it result echo"false" does work. -.-

Comment: Grab firebug, or use your browsers built in developer console, to monitor outgoing AJAX requests and incoming response. A lot of times that can help find errors. Additionally, check your error logs for your HTTP server and PHP. Warning: This code is vulnerable to SQL injection AND is using deprecated API's. Please see the documentation for PDO and mysqli

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're checking for an error code inside your success function. If your script returns an HTTP 200 OK header, success will be invoked. Try setting an error header so that your error function is invoked.

This doesn't answer your question exactly I'm afraid, but it's going to make your code easier to read and could very well solve your problem.